# How can I an arrayList(indexOf) to displays the occurrences of a specific number in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

//Program generates 500 random numbers between 0 and 9 and then displays the number of occurrences of each number.

I'm a new programmer, does anyone have any idea how to solve this question using something from the array list, specifically `indexOf`?
The code below is what I coded with simple 1d arrays.

```java
int []randomNum = new int[500];
int zero = 0, one = 0, two = 0, three= 0, four = 0, 
    five = 0, six = 0, seven = 0, eight = 0, nine = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < randomNum.length; i++) {
    randomNum[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(9-0+1));

    if (randomNum[i] == 0) {
        zero++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 1) {
        one++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 2) {
        two++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 3) {
        three++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 4) {
        four++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 5) {
        five++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 6) {
        six++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 7) {
        seven++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 8) {
        eight++;
    } else if (randomNum[i] == 9) {
        nine++;
    }
}
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "Number", "Occurrence");
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "0", zero);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "1", one);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "2", two);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "3", three);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "4", four);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "5", five);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "6", six);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "7", seven);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "8", eight);
System.out.printf( "%-15s  %15s  %n", "9", nine);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better and effective ways to do this but this is my simple solution.

```
Integer[] randomNum={1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5,3,2,1};
    Set<Integer> set= new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(randomNum));
    System.out.println(set);
    int count=0;
    for (Integer i:set){
        for (Integer j:randomNum){
            if (i ==j){
                count++;
            }
        }
        count=0;
        System.out.println("number of "+i +" is "+ count);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite ok to use plain `int[]` to count the frequencies of the elements, and use of `List`/`ArrayList` and their methods seems to be a bit redundant.  Upon calculating the frequencies, the array may be converted into
the list.

However, existing solution offers a lot of duplicated code which may be reduced significantly:

1. Array `randomNum` is redundant, a single random digit may be calculated
2. It's better to use array instead of separate `int` values to count and print frequencies.
3. It's better to use method `nextInt` of class `Random` instead of calculating with `Math.random()`

```java
final int SEQ_LENGTH = 500;
final int NUM_COUNT = 10;

int[] frequency = new int[NUM_COUNT];

Random randomGenerator = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < SEQ_LENGTH; i++) {
    int num = randomGenerator.nextInt(NUM_COUNT);
    frequency[num]++;
}

System.out.printf( "%s  %s%n", "Number", "Occurrence");

for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf( "%6d  %10d %n", i, frequency[i]);
}

List<Integer> counts = Arrays.stream(frequency).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(counts);

int digit = 2;
System.out.printf("The occurrence of %d's is %d%n", digit, counts.get(digit));
```

Output:

```
Number  Occurrence
     0          54 
     1          40 
     2          45 
     3          57 
     4          47 
     5          50 
     6          59 
     7          50 
     8          47 
     9          51 
[54, 40, 45, 57, 47, 50, 59, 50, 47, 51]
The occurrence of 2's is 45
```